# What are the slots on my character information when I use cat form?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What are the slots (see pic below) that I get under my character bar when I enter cat mode? I'm a night elf restoration druid.

Also: should the bar on which my name is placed be full? does it indicate anything?

[image: weird slots]

Comment: I'm surprised those combopoints are displayed on YOUR character unitframe. AFAIK Combo points in Classic are target-bound.

Comment: @Nzall Yes, and when you switch targets you lose all your combo points.

Comment: @Dulkan I didn't start playing until late TBC. And during that time period, Combo Points were displayed on your target's unitframe AFAIK. At the very least that was the case in Wrath of the Lich King and beyond all the way through to when they were made player bound.

Comment: @Nzall Ah yes, I misunderstood. That screenshot from the OP is from retail. Combo points are diplayed on the targets unitframe in classic, you remember correctly.

Comment: @Dulkan Then I think this question is tagged wrongly with the classic tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bar on which your name is placed is simply a place for your name. It doesn't do anything other than displaying it.

The slots below your unit frame are reserved for combo points.

Rogues and druids in cat form have two resources: Energy and Combo points.

There are **generator spells** like [Claw](https://classicdb.ch/?spell=1082) for example. They will cost energy and generate combo points. Those usually don't deal too much damage on their own.

Then there are **spender spells** like [Rip](https://classicdb.ch/?spell=9492). Those spells will consume all combo points you have built and they will amplify their effect, based on the amount of combo points consumed.